# How can i skip the current sql Query on access denied?

Tags: python, mariadb

I have a database with a user for my webApp. The user only has the privileges to SELECT, DROP and CREATE.

I have written a small API with fastAPI that takes the file and does some minor cleanup things with it. After that the file is passed to the mysql server

(EDIT for better understanding)
The SQL-File looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  email varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  password varchar(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT into users (id, name, email, password) VALUES (1, 'test', 'test@gmail.com', 'password');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS books (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  price int not null,
  authorName varchar(255) NOT NULL
);

create table if not exists orders (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  userId INT NOT NULL,
  bookId INT NOT NULL,
  quantity INT NOT NULL
);

create table if not exists adventureBookings(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    country varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    city varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    price int not null
);
```

it gets read and then saved as a String. Then the user webApp with limited privileges is going to execute these SQL-Queries all at once, but because he isn't allowed to do the insert a error is thrown by the database and the execution of the SQL-Skript stops

So create table for users will be executed then the insert comes which isn't allowed and the tables books, orders and adventureBookings are not beeing created.

The question is: Is there a setting for the mysql server to just ignore denied errors or what could i do to ensure that all tables will get executed or should i try something else?

Comment: Does the access denied scenario throw an error - if yes, what is the traceback? Generally, the query execution can be wrapped in a `try/except` block, where the `except` is designed to catch a *specific* error. Therefore, it would be helpful to see the traceback from the access denied scenario.

Comment: Yes it throws this Error: INSERT command denied to user 'webApp'@'172.18.0.1' for table '......_users'. The problem is that there are still tables left to be created and they won't execute because a Exception was thrown and it's now in the except block

Answer (score 0):

Either you parse your SQL statement before executing, or you ignore the exception:

```
import mariadb

....

for line in lines:
    try:
        cursor.execute(line)
    except Exception as err:
        if err.errno == ERR.ER_ACCESS_DENIED:
            pass
```

Comment: that's not possible because it can't be executed line by line, there are multiline create statements. It's one big string with n amount of create table statements

Comment: why do not split it into separate statements?

Comment: I have done this by now but i would like to know if there is a setting for the mariadb server that is capable of skipping errors

Comment: It's not the server's job to ignore errors, it's the application's job